# How to use multiple Exim SMTP AUTH methods (dovecot and plaintext)

Tags: authentication, smtp, exim

I would like to configure Exim to allow SMTP AUTH logins using the same credentials as for a Dovecot IMAP server on the same machine, but I would also like to allow additional sets of credentials so I can allow network devices to send e-mails through the Exim server without giving them credentials to an IMAP mailbox.

So I have implemented a `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` auth for Exim, using `driver = dovecot`, and I can use SMTP AUTH with my Dovecot credentials, great.

However if I add another two `PLAIN` and `LOGIN` auth methods, this time using `driver = plaintext` instead (to look up the AUTH credentials from a local file), I get an error saying:

> two server authenticators (dovecot_login and file_login) have the same public name (LOGIN)

Is it correct that you can only have one SMTP AUTH method, and it is not possible to fall back and try any others if they are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up [asking the Exim devs about this](https://lists.exim.org/lurker/message/20170319.035904.ed961d9d.en.html) and the answer is unfortunately that it cannot be done directly, as although the `plaintext` authenticator can be extended, the `dovecot` one cannot.

The only solution is to move to an external authentication method like SASL that both Exim and Dovecot can use.